# NEVPNManager or NEPacketTunnelProvider for VPN

Tags: ios, swift, vpn, networkextension, nevpnmanager

I am try create VPN using NEVPNManager, I am use Certificate authentication and IKEv2 protocol. When vpn was installed on iPhone and I am try connect to server, I get this error:

```
Code Block 
Connection 8: received failure notification
nw_flow_add_write_request [C8.1 (Ip&Port) failed channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] cannot accept write requests
nw_write_request_report [C8] Send failed with error "Socket is not connected"
Connection 5: received failure notification
```

only FIRST time after installation, then I am nothing get from VPN.

In this question
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/84679

> If you want to continue down the NEVPNManager path you will have to
> get a trusted CA to issue you a certificate for your VPN server answer
> by eskimo.

I am decide create VPN use NEPacketTunnelProvider but I am don't understand completely all what should I am expected when I will be try that.

How more lot of work will be there?

I can create VPN with IKEv2 for users without certificate CA trusted?

Or good reason will be change authentication method from certificate to login and password for IKEv2 or change protocol on IPsec and use login, pass & secret to authentication method?

### Heading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am decided accepted way use NEVPNManager because I am need just access to blocked web site and it's all, if I am will want do something with traffic or added some cool feature to my vpn I am must will be use NEPacketTunnelProvider.  NEPacketTunnelProvider it's enterprise solution and for it need more work.